# CSS Operations with calc()

Tags: css, css-calc

I have been working with the `calc()` CSS property and I have one doubt about it:

```css
.main {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  width: (100% - nav);
  background: red;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #292929;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

Like you see in the code I'm trying to subtract `100%` - The nav `WIDTH` that it is in `rem` for the responsive mode, but obviously it doesn't work, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't use selectors in [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) as argument, if you want to subtract the `nav`'s `width` then subtract `nav`'s `width` already set:

```css
.main {
  width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  /* mores styles */
}
```

---

> The `calc()` CSS function can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`,
>   `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is required.
>
> .....
>
> **Expressions**
>
> The expression can be any simple expression combining the following
>   operators, using standard operator precedence rules:
>
> `+`
>       Addition.
>
> `-`
>       Subtraction.
>
> `*`
>       Multiplication. At least one of the arguments must be a `<number>`.
>
> `/`
>       Division. The right-hand side must be a `<number>`.
>
> The operands in the expression may be any length syntax value. You can
>   use different units for each value in your expression, if you wish.
>   You may also use parentheses to establish computation order when
>   needed.

Comment: You seem to have taken it on yourself to exhaustively retag everything from `css` and `calc` to `css-calc`. Moderators are currently discussing whether this is a good or bad idea, please hold off on any further retagging for the time being.

Comment: I didn't retag `css` only `calc`, because I thought there was a gap for `css-calc` function in the site, sorry if I acted in a wrong way.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, just please hold off on further retagging for a little while.

Comment: Yes I will `:)`

Comment: Thanks for waiting. Feel free to proceed, but please  continue to focus on questions that are specifically about `calc`, and not just general CSS questions that incidentally happen to involve using `calc`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am trying to do that, I'm using this [search query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22calc%22+is%3Aquestion+%5Bcss%5D+-%5Bcss-calc%5D) to narrow it down

Comment: I added [css-calc] to some questions about calc() that I answered. Funnily enough, I have very few answers that happen to involve using calc() in proportion to answers to questions that are about the function. I guess I just haven't found myself in many situations in which I needed or greatly benefited from using it. Even my own site's stylesheet contains only two unique uses of calc() out of some 600 declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would see if CSS variables could work and it seems to work for me in Chrome (though, not in Edge). I'm pretty sure compatibility issues might make this answer unacceptable until browser support increases, but I wanted to add it for future visitors or personal projects:

```css
:root {
  --nav-width: 5em;
}

nav {
  background: red;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 1em;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  width: calc(100% - var(--nav-width));
  margin-left: var(--nav-width);
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I thought about it too but [IE and EDGE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) doesn't support at all yet, so I didn't add it in my answer, +1 for future support tho ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. It needs to be a predetermined value such as "10px" or "3rem".

However you can do this:

```
.main {
    /* ... */
    width: calc(100% - 4rem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't substract whole element(nav), it must be exact value:

> `<length>, <frequency>, <angle>, <time>, <number>, or <integer>`

If you want to do it this way consider using preprocessor like Sass, you can add new variable and make it equal to some width value. You can substract then your width and this variable.

Sass way:

```
$nav-width: 10px;

.main {
display: block;
margin-left: 4rem;
width: (100% - $nav-width);
background: red;
}
```

Comment: when quoting something , use the link referall